# Fix x-axis error in bar graph of chart.js library

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

How do I put the times in the middle of the gridline? I'm having the problem that it overlaps with the Y axis, causing the first graph column to only display half of it. I want the time value to lie as shown below
[image]

```js
function fncDraw_MultiBarGraph(ctx, data_x_in, data_y_in, data_num, setting, cardNo) {
    var min, max;
    var inputdata = [];

    min = gGraphCardStartTime[cardNo];
    max = gGraphCardEndTime[cardNo];

    for (j = 0; j < data_y_in.length; j++) {
        var data_x = data_x_in[j];
        var data_y = data_y_in[j];
        var data_y_time = [];
        var tmpDatnum = data_num[j];
        for (i = 0; i < tmpDatnum; i++) {
            data_y_time[i] = { x: moment(data_x[i], "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"), y: data_y[i] };
        }
        inputdata.push(data_y_time);
    }

    var tmpdatasets = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < inputdata.length; i++) {
        var idval = 'id_' + i + '_' + setting[i].Point;
        var tmpdata = {
            yAxisID: idval,
            label: setting[i].label,
            data: inputdata[i],
            backgroundColor: setting[i].backgroundColor,
        };
        tmpdatasets.push(tmpdata);
    }

    // Y scales set
    var tmpyscales = [];
    var halft = Math.ceil(setting.length / 2);

    // left hand
    for (i = halft - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var idval = 'id_' + i + '_' + setting[i].Point;
        var minG = setting[i].Graph[0];
        var maxG = setting[i].Graph[1];
        var tmpdata = {
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            type: "linear",
            id: idval,
            ticks: {
                scaleBeginAtZero: false,
                min: minG,
                max: maxG,
                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                    var decpnt = this.id.split('_')[2];
                    return value.toFixed(decpnt);
                }
            }
        }
        tmpyscales.push(tmpdata);
    }

    // right hand
    for (i = halft; i < inputdata.length; i++) {
        var idval = 'id_' + i + '_' + setting[i].Point;
        var minG = setting[i].Graph[0];
        var maxG = setting[i].Graph[1];
        var tmpdata = {
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            type: "linear",
            id: idval,
            ticks: {
                scaleBeginAtZero: false,
                min: minG,
                max: maxG,
                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                    var decpnt = this.id.split('_')[2];
                    return value.toFixed(decpnt);
                }
            }
        }

        tmpyscales.push(tmpdata);
    }

    var iPeriodTime = (gPeriodTime[cardNo] != null) ? gPeriodTime[cardNo] : 6;
    if (iPeriodTime <= 6) {
        stime = "HH:mm";
    } else {
        stime = "MM/DD";
    }

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: tmpdatasets
        },
        options: {
            //すぐに描画
            animation: {
                duration: 0
            },
            hover: {
                animationDuration: 0
            },
            // ラインのラベル表示しない
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            legendCallback: function (chart) {
                var text = [];
                var length = chart.data.datasets.length;
                text.push('<ul class="chart-legend" >');
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    text.push('<li><input id="idlabel' + i + chart.id + '" type="checkbox" class= "checkbox' + i + '" checked="checked" style="border: 1px solid #ffffff; background-color:' + chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor + '">');
                    if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
                        text.push(chart.data.datasets[i].label);
                    }
                    text.push('</li>');
                }
                text.push('</ul>');
                return text.join('');
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                        // return tooltipItem.yLabel.toFixed(decpnt);
                        const decpnt = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].yAxisID.split('_')[2];
                        return tooltipItem.yLabel.toFixed(decpnt);
                    },
                },
            },
            //軸の設定
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: true,
                        maxTicksLimit: 14,
                        max: max,
                        min: min
                    },

                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true
                    },
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                        unit: "minute",
                        displayFormats: {
                            minute: stime
                        },
                        stepSize: gGraphCardXAxisPeriod[cardNo],
                        tooltipFormat: "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss"
                    },
                    position: "bottom"

                }],
                yAxes: tmpyscales
            },
            layout: {
                padding: {
                  bottom: -26
                },
            },
            //自動的にサイズ変更なし
            Responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
    });

    return myChart;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide your chart configuration and data used? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the code above